# LaTeX rendering in incorrect locations

Tags: bug, mathjax, search, hot-questions-list, css

When browsing the site I notices that in the hot question section of the sidebar there was a link to [this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1162555/what-does-echo-21-exactly-do). The link looked a little strange, as shown in the image:

[image: Sidebar rendering bug]

If I'm not mistaken, the dollar-signs in the title triggers LaTeX rendering mode which I guess isn't the idea. Maybe there should be a check to only render Math-SE questions with LaTeX?

Also, when searching, I found [a post with Javscript-code](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/cant-see-the-preview-at-the-bottom-of-a-long-post/9841#9841) which in the post is rendered correctly but in the search results also trigger LaTeX rendering like in the following picture:

[image: Search results rendering bug]

Sorry if this is already noted but I couldn't find any post mentioning this.

Comment: That's a known issue, yes. I'll try to dig up a post.